# Fill java array with objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have to write a quiz tool in java and i am stuck.
I just want to create a question and fill it with answers. The answeres should be in the array "antworten".

MainQuiz.java class:

```
import java.lang.*;
public class MainQuiz {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        QuizFrage qf = new QuizFrage ("Welche Lebensmittel sind gesund?" ,
                 new QuizAntwort ("Apfel" ,"A" , true),
                 new QuizAntwort ("Chips", "B", false),
                 new QuizAntwort ("Orange" , "C", true),
                 new QuizAntwort ("Schokolade" , "D", false));
                qf.FrageStellen();
    }
}
```

QuizAntwort.java class:

```
public class QuizAntwort {
    protected String antwortxt;
    protected Boolean istrichtig;
    protected CharSequence antwortchr;



    public QuizAntwort(String string, String string2, boolean b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }




    public boolean checkAntwort(String gewaehlteAntworten) {
        if (gewaehlteAntworten.contains(antwortchr)) return true; else return false; 
    }
}
```

and QuizFrage.java class

```
public class QuizFrage {
private String fragentext;
private QuizAntwort antworten[];



public QuizFrage(String FrageString, QuizAntwort quizAntwort1,
        QuizAntwort quizAntwort2, QuizAntwort quizAntwort3,
        QuizAntwort quizAntwort4){

    fragentext = FrageString;

}



public void FrageStellen(){

    System.out.println(fragentext);
    for (QuizAntwort curantwort: antworten){
        System.out.println(curantwort.antwortchr + ": " + curantwort.antwortxt);
    }
} 
}
```

How do I fill the array "antworten" with quizantwort1,quizantwort2... ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html):

```
public QuizFrage(String fragentext, QuizAntwort... antworten){
    this.fragentext = fragentext;
    this.antworten = antworten;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple:

```
antworten = new QuizAntwort[] {quizAntwort1, quizAntwort2,
                               quizAntwort3, quizAntwort4};
```

Comment: @Puce That is true. But the whole structure of the code in the question has much to improve. Using varargs is not the primary problem.